# What's the best way to broadcast a message to Akka.Net ConsistentHashingPool routees?

Tags: akka.net

This...

```
hasPoolRouter.Tell(new Broadcast(new SendStatus()))
```

Does not work.  The message only makes it to the Routee where the Consistent Hash Id matches which defeats the purpose of Broadcast.

the router actor is defined like this:

```
hasPoolRouter = ... .WithRouter(new ConsistentHashingPool(4))
```

Comment: If this doesn't work `hasPoolRouter.Tell(new Broadcast(new SendStatus()))` then that might be a bug with Akka.NET itself - would you mind reporting an issue?

Comment: I will do a quick sanity check and try to reproduce with a sample first, now that I know for sure the expected behavior is that all actors that are part of that pool should receive the SendStatus message.

Comment: Ok so sanity check completed and I am insane.  After creating a separate sample with just this stuff to isolate, I realize what the issue is/was.  My code is set up with clustering and when the deployment is set where cluster.enabled=on it only creates one of these per cluster node. I am only running one node here locally so it is only being delivered to the one deployed on my local node.  When I set cluster.enabled=off then it creates all of them locally and they all get it.

Comment: I also found that had two different configurations for the same actor path and was causing it to appear that all of them were local(they were but it was a silly configuration error causing the clustered one to map to only one of the pooled routers). Just a mess of a config and totally my fault. No bug to report just a lesson learned.

Answer (score 0):

I was intending to have a pool of these locally and was running in a clustered configuration and only one was created locally...so the broadcast was only going to the one local instance. I also made a mistake in the configuration and had two configs using the same actor route making things worse.  Good thing that came out of it is that I better understand how this stuff works by screwing it up.

For clarification I had both a clustered one and a non-clustered one configured at the same actor path. I was sending the broadcast to the clustered IActorRef and it was delivered to only one of the multiple pooled non clustered ones. IF I had been running two nodes then two would have received it but not all and may have clued me in.